# How to modify Function in flutter?

Tags: function, flutter

code:

```
class MenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String) onItemClick;
  const MenuWidget({Key key, this.onItemClick}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          sliderItem('Home', Icons.home,context),
          sliderItem('Setting', Icons.settings,context),
          sliderItem('LogOut', Icons.arrow_back_ios,context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget sliderItem(String title, IconData icons) => ListTile(
      title: Text(title,),
      leading: Icon(icons),
      onTap: () {
        onItemClick(title);
      });
}
```

The variable `title` will show the clicked item's name,such as "LogOut" or "Setting",I want to modify onItemClick to navigate to different pages,like `router.navigateTo(context, '/welcome')`,but I dont know how to use onItemClick,Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          sliderItem('Home', Icons.home,context,(){
          //todo
          router.navigateTo(context, '/welcome');
          }),
          //Other items...
        ],
      ),
    );

 Widget sliderItem(String title, IconData icons, VoidCallback onClicked) => ListTile(
      title: Text(title,),
      leading: Icon(icons),
      onTap: onClicked
     );
```

**Method 2 (As you are using named routes !**

```
 return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          sliderItem('Home', Icons.home,'welcome'),
          //Other items...
        ],
      ),
    );

 Widget sliderItem(String title, IconData icons, String route) => ListTile(
      title: Text(title,),
      leading: Icon(icons),
      onTap: (){
       router.navigateTo(context, '/' + route);
      }
     );
```